# Using a server in android to run code

Tags: android, python

I have a second laptop running kali linux which is not used at all, meaning it can be running anytime as a server for my application. So what I actually want to do is connect from my application to my server and send some data, on the server run a python program that uses this code and return some data back. I never tried to work with servers, can I even turn my computer into a server for my application? does this cost any money? can I run a python code on the server and return the results?

I know I haven't published any code but I actually don't know how to start this project and I can use some help so can someone refer me to something to start with? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not Android-related definitely.

You simply need to educated yourself about networking. Yes, it will cost you some money - you spend them buying few books and some hardware for building home network.

After about 3-6-12 months of playing with your home network you will find your question rather simple to answer.

Comment: So what I am looking for is a web server?

Comment: probably, yes. It depends on the nature of python code you need to run.

Comment: and do I need to buy something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldSP1keK8qk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBpuvPW0aHa7mKdn_k9SPKO&index=27 or I actually can use my own laptop for free?

Comment: of course, you can experiment with your laptop - runninng Linux on it you can set up even your own cloud inside it. Basically, you need to study networking. This can be done without money, just reading online resources; but in reality byuing some good books can short your learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to networking, you needn't spend any money at all. You will need to learn basic networking, and how the client-server architecture works.

You've mentioned Python, which I assume you're familiar with. Write a basic client-server program in Python first (you can run both the client-side and server-side on the same computer) to experiment with. Take a look at the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#module-SocketServer). An example (starting) code for both client-side and server-side applications is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example).

Once you've understood how they work, it's very easy to adapt the server-side code for your specific application, and to translate the client-side code into Java for your Android application.

Hope it helps!